# halachic status of a mezuzah with printed scroll

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

What is the halachic status of a mezuzah that has a printed scroll with what appears to be paper, rather than handwritten on parchment? Is it simply a "cheaper" scroll or is it the mezuzah not kosher without a proper scroll?

Comment: Definitely not kosher.

Comment: "appears to be paper": make sure it's not parchment. Hint: the letters on a valid _m'zuza_ are raised, not embedded in the surface as printer toner would be in paper.

Comment: Note that even not kosher, the paper probably requires גניזה, if it has שם מפורש printed on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Mishna Torah (Rambam), laws of mezuzah, chapter 1 sections 9 and 10 clearly state that a mezuzah should be written on duchsustus (the flesh side of the animals skin), and that if it's on klaf (the side of the skin where the hair grew) or gvil (a full piece of skin before it's divided into klaf and duchsustus) it's acceptable. In any event, it must be written on a kosher animal's hide.

ט. אף על פי שכך היא הלכה למשה מסיני אם כתב ספר תורה על הקלף כשר ולא נאמר גויל אלא למעט דוכסוסטוס שאם כתב עליו הספר פסול וכן אם כתב את המזוזה על הקלף או על הגויל כשר לא אמרו על דוכסוסטוס אלא למצוה:‏

י. אין כותבין ספרים תפילין ומזוזות על גבי עור בהמה טמאה ועוף וחיה הטמאים אבל כותבין על גבי עור בהמה וחיה ועוף טהורים ואפילו נבלות וטריפות שלהן ואין כותבין על גבי עור הדג הטהור מפני הזוהמא שאין הזוהמא פוסקת בעיבודה:‏

Comment: Since the initial query also raised the question of handwriting vs. printing, I imagine that ought to be reflected in the answer as well.

Comment: Actually, the Rambam thought duchsustus was the hair side while klaf was the flesh side. He's quite explicit in a number of responsa about this. You're quoting from an edition with a bad girsa.

Answer (score 3):

Not worth the paper it's printed on. The mezuzah *is* the scroll, hand written with special ink on parchment in the correct order. The (often) pretty case that people tend to call the mezuzah is just that - a pretty case. A kosher scroll is kosher even if attached without a case (suitably protected) but the case *cannot* be kosher without a kosher scroll inside.

Comment: Why isn't it worth the paper it's printed on? More importantly: I know you're correct, but [edit]ing in a citation to a source that indicates as much would be valuable.